# MSword alignments with the help of script

Tags: ms-word

The Scenario is I'm given a word document and i need to do some alignments like
Giving double spaces after a fullstop if it starts with a Caps if not single space. 
Can similar stuffs can be done with a script rather than doing a lot of manual work?
If yes, Please help. 
Thanks.

Comment: FYI I have basic knowledge in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache POI can be used. It is the java API for MS Documents. And Apache POI - HWPF - It is the java API to handle MSWord files